# Address cleansing software compatible with ArcGIS

Tags: arcmap, geocoding, address

I am looking for an address cleansing program i.e, a program that takes an address and cleans up misspellings, corrects city or zip as well as correcting wrong prefixes and/or suffixes. Ideally, said program would be compatible with ArcGIS so the geocoding process can be automated. Does anyone know of the existence of such a program? I have searched high and low to no avail. The addresses are usually provided by the user. For example they might provide 150 main AVE, san diego ca. When in fact it's supposed to be 150 main ST, san diego ca. I need a program that can catch such errors.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give some examples of how your addresses are stored in your database.  Addresses are problematic as addresses can be stored in numerous ways, and those ways are usually to make it easy to do something with the addresses, not to make them easy to clean.

Comment: The addresses are usually provided by the user. For example they might provide 150 main AVE, san diego ca. When in fact it's supposed to be 150 main ST, san diego ca. I need a program that can catch such errors.

Comment: How do you expect it to know that `150 Main Ave` is incorrect?

Comment: There's actually a program that does this. It's called QAS by pitney bowes. I don't like it because it's cumbersome to set up and is based on mapinfo as opposed to ArcGIS. Anyway it compares the address against a database of all known possible addresses for a specific city, zip or state and makes the corrections. Atleast that's how I understand it to work. I could be wrong.

Comment: QAS is by Experian not Pitney Bowes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Python lib that standardizes US addresses, https://github.com/datamade/usaddress.

Comment: I actually use usaddress to parse addresses. Can it actually make corrections to the input address?

Comment: No. not yet. (author here)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification fgregg. I love your product :). Is this something you're considering adding to usaddress?